# How to delete file of the current user in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, file-io, directory

I want to delete a file the user logged in using the function `DeleteFile()` library  and I'm not getting ...

I tried this:

```
DeleteFile ("c: \ \ users \ \% username% \ \ file");
```

also tried to capture the user name like this:

```
TCHAR name [UNLEN + 1];
UNLEN DWORD size = + 1;
GetUserName (name, & size);
```

but did not know to put the variable `name` function `DeleteFile()`.

Answer (score 1):

The only clean way to get the user's profile directory is to use the [SHGetSpecialFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762204%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API with the appropriate [CSIDL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762494%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) code (in your case CSIDL_PROFILE). Here is a short (untested) example:

```
char the_profile_path[MAX_PATH]; 
if (SHGetSpecialFolderPath(NULL, the_profile_path, CSIDL_PROFILE, FALSE) == FALSE) 
{
    cerr << "Could not find profile path!" << endl;
    return;
}

std::ostringstream the_file;
buffer << the_profile_path << "\\file";

if (DeleteFile(buffer.c_str()) == TRUE)
{
    cout << buffer << " deleted" << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << buffer << " could not be deleted, LastError=" << GetLastError() << endl;
}
```

Every other way to "construct" the user's profile path or any other special folder of Windows could lead to serious troubles. For example it reduces portability of your application if the profile location changes in a future version (as happened between Windows XP and Vista), or if parts of the path are language dependent (shouldn't be an issue anymore since Vista I think) or the user relocates the profiles (could be an issue in administrated environments, etc.

Please also note that the place where you are supposed to create files for your application is not the profile's root path but the AppData or the LocalAppData (both can be queried using the appropriate CSIDL) folders.

Answer (score 0):

After you get the user name, put together a string that includes it along with the other pieces you care about. I'd consider something on this general order:

```
TCHAR name [UNLEN + 1];
DWORD size = UNLEN+1;
GetUserName(name, &size);

std::ostringstream buffer;

buffer << "C:\\users\\" << user_name << "\\file";

DeleteFile(buffer.str().c_str());
```

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand, you have trouble passing the username to the function.
Why not simply make a new string and pass it to the function like so:

```
TCHAR name [UNLEN + 1];
UNLEN DWORD size = + 1;
GetUserName (name, & size);
TCHAR path [MAX_PATH + 1] = "c: \ \ users \ \";
strcat(path, name);
strcat(path,"\ \ file");
DeleteFile (path);
```